# How can I SELECT rows that are not number

Tags: mysql, select, numbers, where-clause

How can I select rows in MySQL that are not numbers?

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM `TABLE`
 WHERE `Column_B` <> Number
```

I know, this is a stupid question, but I haven't found a solution for this. Column_B is     varchar(3).

Comment: I have to ask... Why are you storing numbers in a VARCHAR?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this sqlfiddle..

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17f28/1

`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE col NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'`

---

If you want to match `real numbers` (`floats`) rather than integers, you need to handle the case above, along with cases where your pattern is between 0 and 1 (i.e. 0.25), as well as case where your pattern has a decimal part that is 0. (i.e. 2.0). And while we're at it, we'll add support for leading zeros on integers (i.e. 005):

```
 ^0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$
```

sql looks like `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE col NOT REGEXP '^0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$'`

Comment: This regexp would catch '000', but wouldn't catch '3.141' or '1.23e-10'.

Comment: thanks michael.. now i updated my answer that would catch float also.

Comment: leading zeroes was already supported before edit, however stll missing signed numbers and scientific notation

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing that, using mysql [regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) operator ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17f301/8/0)):

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE`
WHERE `Column_B` NOT REGEXP '^-?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([Ee][+-][0-9]+)?$';
```

Supports signed/unsigned integers, decimals, and scientific notation.

Note: it is recommended to avoid using sql keywords for entity names, even if you quote them with backticks.

Answer (score -2):

this also will work for you

```
   SELECT col  FROM Table1 
  WHERE col NOT IN ( SELECT col FROM Table1
                   where CAST(col as DECIMAL(10,5)) !=0
                   or Col = '0' )
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea35f/7)

Comment: question is .. select rows that are not numbers. why you are selecting numbers.

Comment: @radha edited with non numbers and decimal. thanks for catch :)

Comment: this fails when input string has digits followed by characters like `1aa` or `3--`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b80efb/1/0